# Subset vector / replace values by lookup based on named vector with partial string matching

Tags: r

I think somehow `grepl` might help, but I struggle with the following:

Similar to subsetting a vector with a named lookup vector (aim is to replace the vector values with the lookup values)

```r
test <- letters[1:3]
lu <- c(a = "a", b = "newb", c = "cool")
lu[test]
#>      a      b      c 
#>    "a" "newb" "cool"
```

I wonder if I can use partial strings for names, so it matches only partially.

```
test2 <- c("Athens hot", "Berlin warm", "Moscow cold")
lu2 <- c(Athens = "a", Berlin = "newb", Moscow = "cool")
# naturally not working
lu2[test2]
#> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
#>   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` as the match/`[` is looking for an exact match

```
sapply(names(lu2), function(x) grep(x, test2))
```

---

Or can use `amatch` from `stringdist` with an appropriate `method` and `maxDist`

```
library(stringdist)
lu2[amatch(names(lu2), test2, method = 'jaccard', maxDist = 0.4)]
```